# conditional formatting not exporting to excel from pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am exporting a pandas dataframe as an excel file from a tutorial, however the resulting file does not include the highlighting and I have no idea why.

To style it:

```
df_styled = df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: orange' for x in df.Margin_rate], axis=0)
```

and then to export it:

```
df_styled.to_excel('excel_python_tutorial_marked.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', index=False)
```

I have made sure to create a new df to export it and everything, where am I going wrong?
Because it's meant to look like this:
[image]

But instead it looks normal in excel:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you need to pass style information explicitly into the openpyxl writer. Maybe [this](https://www.ojdo.de/wp/2019/10/pandas-to-excel-with-openpyxl/) helps.

I have had a good experience with the following, but you might need additional packages and restructure your code a little: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html

Comment: I understand this also works, but according to the documentation and everything. What I have done is not incorrect, it simply just won't highlight! (scroll to the export to excel section) https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html

Comment: Ah, I did not know that yet. I would guess that the explicit mention of `background-color` in the docs means that just using `background` (like you did) is not specific enough.

Can you try using background-color in your style definition? If that does not work, then I don't know either.

Comment: @PoChenLiu did using backgound-color instead of just background work?